# How can I turn an array object into an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to put an array object called hello into a constant called answer. At this time, I want to change the key value of the answer to the value key of hello and the value of the answer to the label value of hello.

how can i do that? i was thinking object entries but i couldn't do that....
is it possible??

this is my code

```
const hello = [
{ label: 'one', value: 'Tangerinefeed' },
{ label: 'two', value: 'dryexamfeed' },
{ label: 'three', value: 'wetfeed' },
{ label: 'forth', value: 'sawdust' },
{ label: 'five', value: 'etc' },
] ;
```

expected answer

```
const answer = {Tangerinefeed: 'one', dryexamfeed: 'two', wetfeed: 'three', sawdust: 'forth', etc: 'five'}
```

Comment: Object.fromEntries - and some code

Comment: What did you try?  Obviously, you iterate the current array and add properties to an object while iterating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve it

```js
const hello = [
{ label: 'one', value: 'Tangerinefeed' },
{ label: 'two', value: 'dryexamfeed' },
{ label: 'three', value: 'wetfeed' },
{ label: 'forth', value: 'sawdust' },
{ label: 'five', value: 'etc' },
] ;

const finalResult = hello.reduce((result, item) => {
  result[item.value] = item.label
  return result
}, {})

console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with forEach method.

```
const hello = [
{ label: 'one', value: 'Tangerinefeed' },
{ label: 'two', value: 'dryexamfeed' },
{ label: 'three', value: 'wetfeed' },
{ label: 'forth', value: 'sawdust' },
{ label: 'five', value: 'etc' },
] ;

const answer = {};

hello.forEach(a=>{ answer[a.value]=a.label})

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

i would use reduce.. ex:

```
const answer = hello.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  prev[cur.value] = cur.label;
  return prev;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever used a `map`?
Hope it helps you.
Thank you.

```js
const hello = [
    { label: 'one', value: 'Tangerinefeed' },
    { label: 'two', value: 'dryexamfeed' },
    { label: 'three', value: 'wetfeed' },
    { label: 'forth', value: 'sawdust' },
    { label: 'five', value: 'etc' },
]

let answer = {};
hello.map(h => {
    answer[h.value] = h.label;
    return true;
});
console.log(answer);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).